# Telerik RadTextBox, It should allow only 300 characters but condition is only 3 rows and 100 character per row

Tags: c#, telerik

This is my code...It should allow only 3 Rows and 100 characters for row

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAdd1" TabIndex="10" runat="server" 
    Rows="3" Columns="100" Width="300px" MaxLength="300" 
    TextMode="MultiLine"> </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Format:

```
123.....100
123.....100
123...100
```

and Tool Tip Should used for showing the maximum limit..

Thanks

Comment: My Code:      <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAdd1" TabIndex="10" runat="server"  Rows="3" Columns="100" Width="300px" MaxLength="300" TextMode="MultiLine">
                                                            </telerik:RadTextBox>

Comment: Some information are missing : *1/. What happend when I enter the char 101 on line one?* Insert linebreak or Do not register the key?Same question on line 2 and 3. *2/.Why?* Can't you parse the result text to add Line break?

Comment: 2 solutions: 3`RadTextBox MaxLength="100" ` Or 1 `RadTextBox  MaxLength="300"` and you add LineBreak every 100. Btw 300 with or with out the linebreak? 298 Char or 300 Char ?

Comment: After 101 on line one it should go to line two.

Comment: TextBox Should allow only two enter's..If third enter  button is clicked it should not allow

Comment: There is Something wrong in your design. First How could 100 char per line fit in a 300px box? You ask for charactere per line? but it don't work like this. You want 2 "Enter". Use the on key press to cancel a key. Or the on text changed.

Comment: But first [edit] your question to make it answerable. As for now it's really not clear what you want. Whatever we conceive well we express clearly, and words flow with ease